# Calculating average in assembly

Tags: visual-c++, assembly, x86, masm, inline-assembly

I have a program to take user input (as many as the user wants to enter) and calculate the average in assembly. Even with clearing the registers by using xor and mov eax,0; I cannot get the number to come out right. Thanks for any help in advance!

Sample I/O:

```
70 
88 
90 
77 
-1
```

The answer I get is always a VERY high number

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int score = 0, avg = 0, total=0, counter = 0;

void pnt()
{
cout << "Enter your score (-1) to stop: ";
}
void gtsc()
{
cin >> score;
}
void pnt_test()
{
cout << total << endl;
}

int main()
{

cout << "Let's compute your average score:" << endl;

__asm
{

    xor eax, eax
    xor edx, edx
    fn:
    call pnt
        call gtsc
        cmp score, -1
            je stop
            jne add_1
    add_1: 
        add eax, score
        inc counter
        jmp fn
    stop: 
        cdq
        mov total, eax
        idiv counter
        mov avg, eax
        call pnt_test
}

cout << "Your average is " << avg << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: _EAX_ is getting clobbered when you do `call pnt` `call gtsc`. _EAX_ is considered a volatile register. One very inefficient hack would be to put a `push eax` before `call pnt` and a `pop eax` after `call gtsc`. This would preserve _EAX_ across the function calls. Also going to make the observation that your average will be a whole number since you are doing strictly integer arithmetic and the way you have done your results you will get them rounded down to the nearest whole number. so values of 2 and 3 would yield 2 as an average.

Comment: Since I am in an assembly class and havn't learned much of anything yet I just moved score to eax and added eax to total. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to keep the total in `eax` but that's clobbered by the `pnt` and `gtsc` functions.  You might want to add to `total` instead, and load that before the division. For example:

```
fn:
call pnt
    call gtsc
    cmp score, -1
        je stop
        jne add_1
add_1: 
    mov eax, score
    add total, eax
    inc counter
    jmp fn
stop: 
    mov eax, total
    cdq
    idiv counter
    mov avg, eax
    call pnt_test
```

PS: learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Eww, don't keep even more stuff in memory when you still have plenty of call-preserved registers to use for `counter` and `total`.  @Keenan: make your C++ functions return their value instead of storing to a global.  And don't `jne add_1` when it's the next instruction anyway.